# Firestore security rules - nested documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to restrict access to group data with the firebase security rules.

Each user has a userId and can be in multiple groups.

All participants in the same group should be able to make changes to the group for all participants.

For example, the user `Wrrhks98BUSLLoGfnUswt2FE57s` should be allowed to make changes to the
group-document `-JrwbcP1OdmjUWxTWHJk` of the user `2B0ABrxKXzr9UdmCP8TuMgqrtBI3`

General structure:

```
collection (groups) 
--> Document (userId) 
   --> Collection (userId) 
       --> Document(groupId)
```

Example:

```
collection (groups) 
    --> Document (2B0ABrxKXzr9UdmCP8TuMgqrtBI3) 
        --> Collection (2B0ABrxKXzr9UdmCP8TuMgqrtBI3) 
            --> Document(-JrwbcP1OdmjUWxTWHJk)
            --> Document(-Mrwtjko3dmjUWxTWHJl)
            --> Document(-LrwbcPtujdqcWxTWHJe)
    --> Document (Wrrhks98BUSLLoGfnUswt2FE57s) 
        --> Collection (Wrrhks98BUSLLoGfnUswt2FE57s) 
            --> Document(-JrwbcP1OdmjUWxTWHJk)
```

i tried this but it doesn' work:

```
match /groups/{userId}/{userId2}/{groupId} {
    allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(request.auth.uid)/$(request.auth.uid)/groupId)
}
```

Comment: There's a guide that discusses how to [structure Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) that you can check, and use the [Firebase Security Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) in testing your security rules. Additionally, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793390/16531380) if this would help you in your case.

Comment: thx, but my main problem is to compare group IDs, not user IDs. So I can‘t use request.auth.uid

Comment: I found posts that you can look up for [group-based permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-group-based-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-72859cdec8f6) and [how to create Firestore security rules based on User Groups](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-firestore-security-rules-based-on-user-groups-defined-in-firestore-documents-824c8be76795). Also, you can still use `request.auth.uid` to look up your uid in your collection group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution :-)

simply that way:

```
match /groups/{userId}/{userId2}/{groupId} {
    allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(request.auth.uid)/$(request.auth.uid)/$(resource.data.id))
}
```